# Angular show NaN value into inputs

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I figure out that by default Angular with the `ng-model` directive doesn't show the `NaN` value into an input:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="calcmouldSugNOfCavitiesCost" disabled
     step=0.01
     ng-model="$parent.mouldTAB.sugNOfCavitiesCost">
```

so if `$parent.mouldTAB.sugNOfCavitiesCost` is equal to `NaN` the input is empty.

Instead of this behaviour i would like to show `NaN`.

it's possible ?

Comment: Since it's a `<input type="number">` it can't contains `NaN` as value (only numbers // letter "e" // signs).

Comment: i tried also to set it as "text" but it remains empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your expected result use below options

Option1 :
1, Change input type to text
2.Check type of input,if string set default value of input to 'NaN'

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input type="text" id="calcmouldSugNOfCavitiesCost" disabled

     ng-model="sugNOfCavitiesCost">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sugNOfCavitiesCost ='123';
  if(typeof($scope.sugNOfCavitiesCost)=='string'){

    $scope.sugNOfCavitiesCost ='NaN';

  }

});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAYoxv

Option2:

To achieve expected result with existing code- input field as number, add one more text field to display 'NaN' incase of string values and using ng-show and ng-hide display input fields according to the value

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" id="calcmouldSugNOfCavitiesCost" disabled ng-model="sugNOfCavitiesCost" ng-hide="toggle">
    <input type="text" disabled value="NaN" ng-show="toggle">
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sugNOfCavitiesCost ='123';
  if(typeof($scope.sugNOfCavitiesCost)=='string'){
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.toggle =true;
    }

});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOpNrw

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's a `<input type="number">` it can't contains `NaN` as value.

Inputs type number can only contains `numbers`, letter *"e"* or signs (+ / -).

On other hand, you can use the `text type`, so you can check if the value is empty in your controller, then you can attribute `NaN` to it, simple as below:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = '';
      
      if (!$scope.test) {
        $scope.test = "NaN";
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calcmouldSugNOfCavitiesCost" ng-model="test" disabled>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.